# Direct2D ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap fails with no error

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I just try to add LoadBitmapFromFile function from sample (from SDK) to my MFC project. So my app fails during runtime on line, no errors, no warnings.

```
hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(pConverter, NULL, ppBitmap);
```

When I debugging it and goes over this line I receive empty window and debug session stops. How to find out what the error is? What could be the cause?

```
HRESULT DemoApp::LoadBitmapFromFile(
ID2D1RenderTarget *pRenderTarget,
IWICImagingFactory *pIWICFactory,
PCWSTR uri,
UINT destinationWidth,
UINT destinationHeight,
ID2D1Bitmap **ppBitmap)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

IWICBitmapDecoder *pDecoder = NULL;
IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource = NULL;
IWICStream *pStream = NULL;
IWICFormatConverter *pConverter = NULL;
IWICBitmapScaler *pScaler = NULL;

hr = pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
    uri,
    NULL,
    GENERIC_READ,
    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
    &pDecoder
    );
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{

    // Create the initial frame.
    hr = pDecoder->GetFrame(0, &pSource);
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Convert the image format to 32bppPBGRA
    // (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM + D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED).
    hr = pIWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // If a new width or height was specified, create an
    // IWICBitmapScaler and use it to resize the image.
    if (destinationWidth != 0 || destinationHeight != 0)
    {
        UINT originalWidth, originalHeight;
        hr = pSource->GetSize(&originalWidth, &originalHeight);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (destinationWidth == 0)
            {
                FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationHeight) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight);
                destinationWidth = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth));
            }
            else if (destinationHeight == 0)
            {
                FLOAT scalar = static_cast<FLOAT>(destinationWidth) / static_cast<FLOAT>(originalWidth);
                destinationHeight = static_cast<UINT>(scalar * static_cast<FLOAT>(originalHeight));
            }

            hr = pIWICFactory->CreateBitmapScaler(&pScaler);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pScaler->Initialize(
                        pSource,
                        destinationWidth,
                        destinationHeight,
                        WICBitmapInterpolationModeCubic
                        );
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pConverter->Initialize(
                    pScaler,
                    GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                    WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                    NULL,
                    0.f,
                    WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
                    );
            }
        }
    }
    else // Don't scale the image.
    {
        hr = pConverter->Initialize(
            pSource,
            GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
            WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
            NULL,
            0.f,
            WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
            );
    }
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Create a Direct2D bitmap from the WIC bitmap.
    hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(pConverter, NULL, ppBitmap);
}

SafeRelease(&pDecoder);
SafeRelease(&pSource);
SafeRelease(&pStream);
SafeRelease(&pConverter);
SafeRelease(&pScaler);

return hr;
```

}

Comment: What the D2D debug layer tells ? `D2FactoryOptions.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it tells nothing just silence.